# Adding a column of zeroes to a csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an MxN sparse `csr_matrix`, and I'd like to add a few columns with only zeroes to the right of the matrix. In principle, the arrays `indptr`, `indices` and `data` keep the same, so I only want to change the dimensions of the matrix. However, this seems to be not implemented.

```
>>> A = csr_matrix(np.identity(5), dtype = int)
>>> A.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> A.shape
(5, 5)
>>> A.shape = ((5,7))
NotImplementedError: Reshaping not implemented for csr_matrix.
```

Also horizontally stacking a zero matrix does not seem to work.

```
>>> B = csr_matrix(np.zeros([5,2]), dtype = int)
>>> B.toarray()
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
>>> np.hstack((A,B))
array([ <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <5x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

This is what I want to achieve eventually. Is there a quick way to reshape my `csr_matrix` without copying everything in it?

```
>>> C = csr_matrix(np.hstack((A.toarray(), B.toarray())))
>>> C.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do isn't really what numpy or scipy understand as a reshape. But for your particular case, you can create a new CSR matrix reusing the `data`, `indices` and `indptr` from your original one, without copying them:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

a = sps.rand(10000, 10000, density=0.01, format='csr')

In [19]: %timeit sps.csr_matrix((a.data, a.indices, a.indptr),
...                             shape=(10000, 10020), copy=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.26 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit sps.csr_matrix((a.data, a.indices, a.indptr),
...                             shape=(10000, 10020), copy=False)
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.3 us per loop

In [21]: %timeit sps.csr_matrix((a.data, a.indices, a.indptr),
...                             shape=(10000, 10020))
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.2 us per loop
```

So if you no longer need your original matrix `a`, since the default is `copy=False`, simply do:

```
a = sps.csr_matrix((a.data, a.indices, a.indptr), shape=(10000, 10020))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `scipy.sparse.vstack` or `scipy.sparse.hstack` to do it faster:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, vstack, hstack

B = csr_matrix((5, 2), dtype=int)
C = csr_matrix((5, 2), dtype=int)
D = csr_matrix((10, 10), dtype=int)

B2 = vstack((B, C))
#<10x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
#        with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

hstack((B2, D))
#<10x12 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
#        with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Note that the output is a `coo_matrix`, which can be efficiently converted to the `CSR` or `CSC` formats.